# ionic2 ion-checkbox - use integers instead of boolean

Tags: angular, ionic2

How can I get ion-checkbox values as 1 and 0 instead of true and false.
Because, ng-true-value and ng-false-value is depreciated in angular2.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the type as number and you can use as below

```
 <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="mycheck"></ion-checkbox>
```

The value of checkbox is displayed as `{{getValue()}}`

```
getVal(){
  return +this.mycheck;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0L1ToQx4AHKGcBHINziq?p=preview)